Sklearn Column Transformer not working for mixed data types
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



# Selecting numerical columns
numerical_cols = data[['MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges', 'tenure']].to_numpy()

# Selecting an ordinal column
ordinal_cols = data[['Contract']].to_numpy()

# Selecting categorical columns
categorical_cols = data[['PaperlessBilling', 'PaymentMethod']].to_numpy()

# Selecting the target column
target_col = data['Churn'].to_numpy()



# Define the order for the 'Contract' column
contract_order = ['Month-to-month', 'One year', 'Two year']

# Create transformers for the numeric and categorical data
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
('scaler', StandardScaler()),
('scaler', StandardScaler())])

# Assuming 'contract_column' is the name of the contract column in your DataFrame
ordinal_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('ordinal', OrdinalEncoder(categories=[contract_order]))])

# Assuming 'categorical_columns' is the list of other categorical columns in your DataFrame
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
     ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
      ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

# Create a ColumnTransformer to apply the transformations to the correct columns
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numerical_cols),
        ('ord', ordinal_transformer, ordinal_cols),  
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_cols)
    ])




# Create a pipeline that combines the preprocessor with the model
model = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                        ('classifier', LogisticRegression())])

print(numerical_cols)
print(ordinal_cols)
print(categorical_cols)


# Separate the features and the target
X = data[numerical_cols + ordinal_cols + categorical_cols]
y = data[target_col].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Yes' else 0) # Encoding 


# Split data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)




---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 68
     65 print(categorical_cols)
     67 # Separate the features and the target
---> 68 X = data[numerical_cols + ordinal_cols + categorical_cols]
     69 y = data[target_col].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Yes' else 0) # Encoding 
     72 # Split data into train and test sets

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

I am trying to do logistic regression with data which involves a variety of datatypes. I split the data into the numerical_cols, ordinal_cols and categorical_cols variables. However, when I print them I see they have not been transformed. I think this is the reason for the error. How can I transform the variables correctly?

Not directly related to your question, but those pipelines repeating the same transformer multiple times is redundant. Each step in the pipeline will get applied to all columns in the relevant column list of the ColumnTransformer.

The column specification for each transformer in a ColumnTransformer (your numerical_cols etc.) should be a list of column names, not the actual dataframe consisting of those columns.  That is,
numerical_cols = data[['MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges', 'tenure']].to_numpy()

should just be
numerical_cols = ['MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges', 'tenure']

(There are other options for the column specification, see the docs.)

Thanks for the answer! This looks a lot better! @BenReiniger
